# Query Asterisk CDR in MYSQL to list inbound calls by SIP number?

Tags: mysql, sql, asterisk, pbx

Is it possible to query the CDR database to list the total number of inbound calls per inbound phone number over a given period?

I would like to have the output like:

```
Inbound Telephone number : Count calls received
------------------------   --------------------

0123456789               : 124

098756431                : 43

0123456798               : 39

0123456788               : 14
```

I have the CDR database in MYSQL but looking at the data I can't seem to figure out how to identify which calls are incoming and what phone number and SIP provider they used to dial in.

I am trying to assess how often some of our direct dial numbers are used over a given period.

The columns I have to query in MYSQL:

```
acctid
calldate
clid
src
dst
dcontext
channel
dstchannel
lastapp
lastdata
duration
billsec
disposition
amaflags
accountcode
uniqueid
userfield
did
recordingfile
cnum
cnam
outbound_cnum
outbound_cnam
dst_cnam
import_cdr
```

Which look to be documented here: http://asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/asterisk-SysAdmin-SECT-1.html

However some columns which look like channel do not clearly tell me what the inbound caller called and if the call was inbound or outbound.

Had a google search, can't seem to find an answer for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that none of the numbers were being used which is what was throwing me off.

Simply querying the DID column solves it.

```
SELECT 'xxxxxxxxxxx' as 'tel', count(*) as 'count' from CDR where did = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
```

I then used EXCEL to create a huge union with all of the did numbers and found that this works.

--

Would still like to know how to identify inbound and outbound calls however from this list as it would be useful in the future.